# accessing boundaries of array without duplicating lots of code

Tags: arrays, fortran

When I try to compile my code using `-fcheck=all` I get a runtime error since it seems I step out of bounds of my array dimension size. It comes from the part of my code shown below. I think it is because my loops over i,j only run from `-ny` to `ny`, `-nx` to `nx` but I try to use points at `i+1,j+1,i-1,j-1` which takes me out of bounds in my arrays.  When the loop over `j` starts at `-ny`, it needs `j-1`, so it immediately takes me out of bounds since I'm trying to access `-ny-1`.  Similarly when `j=ny, i=-nx,nx`.

My question is, how can I fix this problem efficiently using minimal code?

I need the `array grad(1,i,j)` correctly defined on the boundary, and it needs to be defined exactly as on the right hand side of the equality below, I just don't know an efficient way of doing this.  I can explicitly define `grad(1,nx,j), grad(1,-nx,j), etc,` separately and only loop over `i=-nx+1,nx-1,j=-ny+1,ny-1` but this causes lots of duplicated code and I have many of these arrays so I don't think this is the logical/efficient approach.  If I do this, I just end up with hundreds of lines of duplicated code that makes it very hard to debug.  Thanks.

```
integer :: i,j
integer, parameter :: nx = 50, ny = 50
complex, dimension (3,-nx:nx,-ny:ny) :: grad,psi
real, parameter :: h = 0.1

do j = -ny,ny
do i = -nx,nx

    psi(1,i,j) = sin(i*h)+sin(j*h)
    psi(2,i,j) = sin(i*h)+sin(j*h)    
    psi(3,i,j) = sin(i*h)+sin(j*h)

end do
end do

do j = -ny,ny
do i = -nx,nx

    grad(1,i,j) = (psi(1,i+1,j)+psi(1,i-1,j)+psi(1,i,j+1)+psi(1,i,j-1)-4*psi(1,i,j))/h**2 & 

                - (psi(2,i+1,j)-psi(2,i,j))*psi(1,i,j)/h & 

                - (psi(3,i,j+1)-psi(3,i,j))*psi(1,i,j)/h &

                - psi(2,i,j)*(psi(1,i+1,j)-psi(1,i,j))/h &

                - psi(3,i,j)*(psi(1,i,j+1)-psi(1,i,j))/h

end do
end do
```

If I was to do this directly for `grad(1,nx,j), grad(1,-nx,j)`, it would be given by

```
   do j = -ny+1,ny-1

       grad(1,nx,j) = (psi(1,nx,j)+psi(1,nx-2,j)+psi(1,nx,j+1)+psi(1,nx,j-1)-2*psi(1,nx-1,j)-2*psi(1,nx,j))/h**2 & 

                - (psi(2,nx,j)-psi(2,nx-1,j))*psi(1,nx,j)/h & 

                - (psi(3,nx,j+1)-psi(3,nx,j))*psi(1,nx,j)/h &

                - psi(2,nx,j)*(psi(1,nx,j)-psi(1,nx-1,j))/h &

                - psi(3,nx,j)*(psi(1,nx,j+1)-psi(1,nx,j))/h

       grad(1,-nx,j) = (psi(1,-nx+2,j)+psi(1,-nx,j)+psi(1,-nx,j+1)+psi(1,-nx,j-1)-2*psi(1,-nx+1,j)-2*psi(1,-nx,j))/h**2 & 

                - (psi(2,-nx+1,j)-psi(2,-nx,j))*psi(1,-nx,j)/h & 

                - (psi(3,-nx,j+1)-psi(3,-nx,j))*psi(1,-nx,j)/h &

                - psi(2,-nx,j)*(psi(1,-nx+1,j)-psi(1,-nx,j))/h &

                - psi(3,-nx,j)*(psi(1,-nx,j+1)-psi(1,-nx,j))/h

   end do
```

Comment: I suspect that your only option is to unroll the end cases from the nested loops or make use of `if-then-else-endif` constructs to avoid the out of bound array accesses.  The `if-then-else-endif` construct will likely slow your loops way down.

Comment: @evets Unrolling the end cases causes hundreds of lines of duplicated code since I actually have grad(1,i,j), grad(2,i,j)...up to grad(5,i,j), and the right hand sides of the equalities are much more complicated than shown above.  How can I instead do this using an `if-then-else-endif statement`? Thanks

Comment: In the above inner loop,  for example, you have `if (i == nx) then  tmp = XXXX else tmp = psi(2,i+1,j) endif`  where XXXX enforces some boundary condition and `tmp` is used in the grad(1,i,j) expression.

Comment: @evets So what would the `if-then-else-endif` statement be?   How can I write the code to handle the boundaries?  I do not see how I could use that.  I will gladly trade speed for duplicating hundreds of lines of code in which its difficult to debug.

Comment: I forgot about the possibility of using ghost cells.  You define your arrays to have dimension of `-ny-1:ny+1` and `-nx-1:nx+1`.  You then set the ghost cells to appropriate boundary values, `psi(1,-ny-1,:) = BC1`, `psi(1,ny+1,:)= BC2`, `psi(1,:,-nx-1) = BC3`, and `psi(1,:,nx+1) = BC4`.

Comment: @evets But my issue isn't with imposing boundary conditions on psi, I need to impose it on grad(1,i,j) for all i,j.   There is no simplified boundary condition for grad, its the exact expression I show above in the code.  So my problem is that when I try to impose the boundary values of the Grad(1,i,j) array, I step out of bounds.

Comment: @JeffFaraci, in the corner case of `i=nx`, for example, what value should the expression use instead of the term `psi(1,i+1,j)`, as there is no corresponding value in the array `psi`?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Im not sure I understand your question, sorry. I'll interpret it as follows, I should take the derivative on the boundary by `(psi(1,nx,j)-psi(1,nx-1,j))/h`.  Basically, I need the derivatives on the boundary which is what `grad` is representing.  However, I'm trying to find an efficient way of doing this.  Similar to how you solved the last problem I posted on here. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues and for the other boundary, `i=-nx`, I should use `psi(1,-nx+1,j)-psi(1,-nx,j)` to take a derivative.  The same holds for the `j=-ny,ny` boundaries.

Comment: Hm... in other words: could you please add to your sample code how would the complete equation of `grad(1,nx,j)` be, if you assigned its value directly?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Yes I can do that, let me do it right now.  My actual code has `grad(1,i,j), grad(2,i,j)`,....up to `grad(5,i,j)`, and there expressions are much longer than what I have above.  Hence why I'm trying to avoid doing this directly as it adds almost 1000 lines of code making it very hard to debug. Thanks

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I just added `grad(1,nx,j), grad(1,-nx,j)` directly.  Note, you can see that this also avoids the corners of the grid though, since I loop over `j=-ny+1,ny-1` which avoids the point `grad(1,nx,ny),grad(1,nx,-ny)`,etc.  You can see coding this `grad` on the boundary quickly becomes lots of duplicated code and its becoming a bit unreasonable I think.  But I now would do the same for `grad(1,i,ny),grad(1,i,-ny)`  and then have to do all the  corners `(nx,ny), (nx,-ny), (-nx,ny), (-nx,-ny)` separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way for you could be using an additional index variable for the boundaries, modified from the original index to avoid getting out-of-bounds. I mean something like this:

```
do j = -ny,ny
  jj = max(min(j, ny-1), -ny+1)
  do i = -nx,nx
    ii = max(min(i, nx-1), -nx+1)
    grad(1,i,j) = (psi(1,ii+1,j)+psi(1,ii-1,j)+psi(1,i,jj+1)+psi(1,i,jj-1)-4*psi(1,i,j))/h**2 &
                - (psi(2,ii+1,j)-psi(2,ii,j))*psi(1,i,j)/h &
                - (psi(3,i,jj+1)-psi(3,i,jj))*psi(1,i,j)/h &
                - psi(2,i,j)*(psi(1,ii+1,j)-psi(1,ii,j))/h &
                - psi(3,i,j)*(psi(1,i,jj+1)-psi(1,i,jj))/h
  end do
end do
```

It's hard for me to write a proper code because it seems you trimmed part of the original expression in the code you presented in the question, but I hope you understand the idea and apply it correctly for your logic.

**Opinions:**

1. Even though this is what you are asking for (as far as I understand), I would not recommend doing this before profiling and checking if assigning the boundary conditions manually after a whole array operation wouldn't be more efficient, instead. Maybe those extra calculations on the indices on each iteration could impact on performance (arguably less than `if` conditionals or function calls). Using "ghost cells", as suggested by @evets, could be even more performant. You should profile and compare.
2. I'd recommend you declaring your arrays as `dimension(-nx:nx,-ny:ny,3)` instead. Fortran stores arrays in column-major order and, as you are accessing values on the neighborhood of the "x" and "y", they would be non-contiguous memory locations for a fixed "other" dimension is the leftest, and that could mean less cache-hits.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I see now that `ii,jj` only run from `-49 to 49`, since `nx=ny=50`, but does this code you posted allow `grad(1,nx,j)` to get defined then?  Im trying to figure out how this works. Or do you suggest using this `max(min...)` but still separately defining `grad(1,nx,j),etc`?  In other words, I am trying to avoid assigning the value of `grad(1,nx,j)` separately, does your solution here solve that problem?

Comment: `ii` and `jj` would be capped between -49,49, but you'd still have access to the indices `i` and `j` to use when needed in the logic, that will indeed reach the boundaries -50,50

Comment: I suggest you, for visualizing this effect, to mentally substitute `i=nx` in the expression I wrote and compare it to the expression you provided for this boundary

Comment: Wow what a unique way of solving the problem I was having. I need to visualize this ya, let me try and do so and implement this. I may have questions for you. If so I'll ask here. I'm still trying to visualize the answer to the last problem of mine You solved. You have helped me a lot so thanks.

Comment: Would you handle a term `grad(1,i,j) = psi(1,i+1,j+1)+psi(1,i-1,j-1)` as just `grad(1,i,j) = psi(1,ii+1,jj+1)+psi(1,ii-1,jj-1)`?  It seems as if you leave `i,j` for the `psi` terms that don't step out of bounds, but for the parts of `psi` that step out of bounds, you always use `ii,jj`.  For some reason I am getting a divergence in my code when I implement this.  Perhaps I am not doing it right.  Thanks a lot

Comment: I think the problem is in the way I define `psi(1,i,j)` initially (my initial condition), I have just posted a new question which addresses the issue.  Obviously, I think the way you have given here to code `grad(1,i,j)` works just fine, its just I am not defining `psi(1,i,j)` correctly for all `i,j`.

Comment: That was just what I was about to write. Review your expressions and the way you consider proper to treat the boundaries. Don't rely on the code I wrote (because I don't have access to the whole logic), but in the idea

Comment: Ya, you're definitely right.  I do not know why these boundary conditions are giving me such a hard time.  I figured they should be easier.  I'm trying to use a quasi-periodic boundary condition on `psi0(1,i,j)` and `grad(1,i,j)` is my differential equation.

Comment: I think the code you wrote is correct, logically it seems to make sense.  However I am unsure how to properly define my initial condition `psi(1,i,j)`, so when I pass that into `grad(1,i,j)`, I get incorrect divergent results.

Comment: What exactly is the reason to use `psi0(i,j,1)` opposed to `psi0(1,i,j)`, I don't really understand your comment on this.  I know you are right i'd just like to understand this a bit more.  I naively thought the two declarations would be the same..

Comment: This is another subject, and would deserve a question by its own. I suggest you to search online about "cpu cache", "array storage" and, specifically, "fortran efficient arrays". I recommend you [this](http://astroa.physics.metu.edu.tr/MANUALS/intel_ifc/mergedProjects/optaps_for/fortran/optaps_prg_arrs_f.htm) and [this](https://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#arrays) sources, bur there are [many](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fortran-array-data-and-arguments-and-vectorization) [more](https://jblevins.org/log/efficient-code).

Answer (score 1):

In somewhat pseudo-code, you can do

```
do j = -ny, ny

   if (j == -ny) then
      p1jm1 = XXXXX    ! Some boundary condition
   else
      p1jm1 = psi(1,i,j-1)
   end if

   if (j == ny) then
      p1jp1 = YYYYY   ! Some other boundary condition
   else
      p1jp1 = psi(1,i,j+1)
   end if

   do i = -nx, ny
      grad(1,i,j) = ... term involving p1jm1 ...  term involving p1jp1 ...
      ...
   end do
end do
```

The j-loop isn't bad in that you are adding 2*2*ny conditionals.  The inner i-loop is adding 2*2*nx conditionals for each j iteration (or 2*2*ny * 2*2*nx conditional).  Note, you need a temporary for each psi with the triplet indices are unique, ie., `psi(1,i,j+1)`, `psi(1,i,j-1)`, and `psi(3,i,j+1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm not quite sure I get it all yet, I have some questions.  Do you mean `i = -nx,nx` for the do loop before `grad(1,i,j)`? And won't that Do loop then just step out of bounds since it'll depend on `i+1`, `i-1` which will try to access `-nx-1,nx+1` which don't exist?

Comment: Additionally, your initial loop over `j` has `p1jm1=psi(1,i,j-1)` but you're not even looping over `i` yet.  I think theres a few mistakes with what you've posted.  do you agree or?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I think in terms of array operations. I would have `p1jm1(-nx:nx) = ...` in my code, and set all values at once in the j-loop.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I dont understand what you mean.  Can you perhaps edit the code so its correct and clearly indicates what you mean?  If you're unable to be clear on what you mean in terms of writing the code, its simply not so helpful.  Thanks for discussing.